# What is the procedure for measuring color contrast around anti-aliasing?

Tags: accessibility, color, contrast

What is the proper method for measuring the color contrast of on-screen elements that are anti-aliased (particularly, but not limited to, text)? Does a standard method even exist?

Here's my specific situation: I'm attempting to comply with WCAG 2.0 for text inside a dropdown menu. A zoomed-in screenshot of the menu is below:

[image: zoomed-in screenshot of anti-aliasing around text]

This is a standard IE11 `<select>` with no custom styling, so the text is nominally `#FFFFFF` on `#000080`. However, the screenshot clearly shows that there are many pixels in the text in a variety of shades of blue and pink, due to anti-aliasing. Depending on which pixel I select as the foreground, I can get contrast as high as **16.0:1** (pure white on dark blue) to at least as low as **2.4:1** (royal blue on dark blue).

My customer's QA people are saying that the contrast is **2.9:1**, much lower than the minimum requirement of **4.5:1**. I don't know what their measurement strategy is, and do not have a direct line of communication to them.

What I want to do now is figure out the correct way to measure this so that I can at least tell my customer-facing team members that we're doing it the right way and hopefully work towards a long-term solution.

The problem is that I don't know what counts as "correct". My Googling has resulted in a lot of definitions of contrast and explanations of why it's important, but nothing about the proper way to measure it. Should I select the highest-contrast pixel I can find? The lowest-contrast pixel? Measure a handful of pixels and average the results? Use a selector that grabs multiple pixels at once? How do I know I have measured the "real", accurate color contrast value in a given situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could just use any software and check it by yourself (for example, by using the eyedropper tool in Photoshop).

However, it doesn't matter at all. Browsers will read `#ffffff` and `#000080` which has a contrast ratio of **16.01:1**.

The aliasing doesn't matter at all in terms of how a browser reads it and accessibility. Please note that aliased and non-aliased text will have obvious differences and may affect readability and aesthetics, but it won't affect how a browser reads it unless you apply CSS changes such as opacity, filter, transform and such.

About the QA people, that's a whole different story. I have no idea how are they measuring things, but unless the values you mention are incorrect, they're doing it wrong. If in doubt, you can use tools like [**Contrast Checker**](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/) or [**WAVE**](https://wave.webaim.org/) if you want to test a full page and elements in context (such as the `select` element you mention)

EDIT: Read the link on Slugolicious comment, and you'll find what to tell your PM in case they insist in measuring aliased text:

> Note 2: Because authors do not have control over user settings as to
>   how text is rendered (for example font smoothing or anti-aliasing),
>   the contrast ratio for text can be evaluated with anti-aliasing turned
>   off.

Comment: Agreed.  Use the colors as defined in the html (#ffffff and #000080) and not a dropper on the anti-aliasing.  If you want the formula, see https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#contrast-ratiodef

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid this was going to be the answer. I found slugolicious's link before I asked here so I know the math and stuff... I was just hoping I could present a technical list of steps to take because that's easier than convincing faceless strangers that they're, as you say, doing it wrong.